# How to consume Spring Data Rest Webservices API with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, restangular

i had been working in a Spring Rest Data API in an application (just for fun).
I have the core made, works fine but now I want to use AngularJS as front-end.
I had work with Jackson (Mapping Java Objects to JSON), but with Spring Rest Data the Json response it's diferent, it has `_embedded`, `_links`, `self`, etc. links that make me confuse. I have something like this in the root url `http://localhost/8080/app/api/tarifas`
[image]

I have used a JS script called `restangular` but i have serveral problems (I'm newbie with Angular)

In my controller i have this
[image]

Check the error 
[image]

If I add a RestangularProvider in my app.config(...) and change the Controller to getList instead get, works fine, but I need several entities data formats.

[image]

Any help it's welcome. If you know a better way please tell me.
Thanks!!

**UPDATE**
I found a form to do this (i don´t know if it's the better) but now my problem is the next:
I have objects that has other objects as attributes (realtionship), and the reference in the JSON is a link (not an object). Then, in the grid; the value of the description's internal object is blank. To get the json data I found this
[image]

Now I have the next content for one register (one of the grid)
[image]

And my grid (In Angular, HTML) looks like this (empty fields)
[image]

How can I retrieve the attribute description from the member `estado`, `categoria`, etc. and show it in the grid. Should make the request to get it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either  angular.toJson or json.stringify

[Angular-toJson documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)

[Json.stringify documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had made another think, I updated the question.